# How to let the cursor push the screen instead of the the screen drag the cursor when scrolling with the mouse?

Tags: scrolling, mouse, iterm2

How to let the cursor push the screen instead of the the screen drag the cursor when scrolling with the mouse?

I switched to iterm 2 on osx, but in the regular osx terminal when i scroll the scrolling moves the cursor not the window. In iterm 2 it only scrolls the window. I can't find the setting to set this back again. I found `set mouse=a` but this doesn't do the trick.

EDIT:

To clarify I do not want a scroll offset. I want the physical scroll action to move the cursor not the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood clearly what you want but maybe the option `scrolloff` is what you're looking for: if you `set scrolloff=10` you will always have 10 lines between your cursor and the bottom of the window when you scroll down, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @statox tried to clarify. Thanks for the hint though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
nnoremap <ScrollWheelUp> k
nnoremap <ScrollWheelDown> j
```

? I can't test on osx though, but it works on my linux installation.

Comment: Brilliantly simple love it.